# How to export customer list with separate fields for first and last names?

Tags: customer-csv

```
Magento 1.9.x
Sendgrid
```

We have been paying for one of the paid versions of Sendgrid for some time and never sent a newsletter out yet. We are getting ready to send a newsletter from within Sendgrid now. We have exported the customer list from Magento by following these steps:

--> Customers --> Manage Customers --> Export to: CSV --> Export

The problem is that when we open the CSV file - it has the first and last name both in 1 column while Sendgrid requires separate columns for first and last name.

How can we export a full customer list out of Magento 1.9.x where first name and last name would be in separate fields of the exported CSV?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in one of 2 ways:

- System --) Import/Export --> where Entity Type = Customers

or

- System --) Import/Export --) Dataflow - Profiles --> Export Customers